# Radio button required if user fills text field

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm having a little problem with form validation.

The form in question is this one:
http://www.elcorteingles.pt/reservas/livros_escolares/index.asp

What I need to do is basically setup the following function:

1. **if** 'input.titulo_books' value (larger than)  0

   **then** radio button is required.

This for each li. So that if the user fills in a book's title, the radio buttons associated are required. I understand the logic but am unable to create the actual result. I'm also using a standard javascript form validation code. Do you suggest I do everything in Jquery for example?

Comment: Can you post your code and make a fiddle?

Comment: If the value is zero, or if no value is inputted, i.e. the value is an empty string. There's a difference.

Comment: So sorry @adeneo, have edited the question accordingly. If the value of the input is larger than 0, because the user has filled in something :P

Comment: @Mooseman, I'll be honest, in this case I wouldn't know where to start. Checking input values and form validations confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your validation to check each field and determine if there is data entered. Then if there is, you need to validate the radio box.

```
// Check each input field
$('.titulo_books').each(function(){

    // If there is data in the field
    if($(this).val().length > 0){

        //run your radio box validation
    }
})
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! But do I need use Jquery to validate the rest of the form before? 

The only Radio group validation functions I've found are dependent on using a plugin. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can use whatever you want to validate the rest of the form. The point of jQuery is to "write less, do more" and it's awesome at doing just that. There's tons of plugins out there that will do the heavy lifting for you. No point in re-inventing the wheel.